# Error 3 after OPEN DATASET if big data volume is processed, none otherwise

Tags: abap

The problem is that I received a ticket from the AMS support team, which I cannot debug because for given input parameters on the selection screen, the program is looping for 10 hours and that's why the program is set as a background job.

The point of the program is that it should save some data in xls file on the application server.

The important thing is that for some input parameters on the selection screen program WORKS (smaller date intervals, also fewer data to work with), but right now I have to explain to the consultant why the program cannot write that much data into the file on the application server.

To conclude, a Background job is linked to the program which is grabbing a lot of data from DB, in some cases when there is an enormous amount of the data, the program cannot open the file for output so there is no data in xls.

My question is, how big the limit for OUTPUT mode in OPEN DATASET is and why I get an "error opening file" when I have bigger intervals in the selection screen.

```
OPEN DATASET lv_file FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING NON-UNICODE
  IGNORING CONVERSION ERRORS.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.  "PROGRAM FAILS HERE, SY-SUBRC eq 3
  |
  |
```

The program works when we select fewer data from DB, I have to provide the answer to the question: "why it fails when I grab a big amount of data.

Error in dialog mode :

[image: error in dialog mode]

Error in background mode :

[image: error in background mode]

Comment: It's very surprising that sy-subrc = 3 because the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapopen_dataset.htm) says that it may return only 0 or 8. An error at OPEN DATASET only in the context of high memory usage may think that it's related. Anyway, you should in parallel contact the SAP support to mention this weird issue.

Comment: Hi, is there something provided in the following fields `sy-msgno, sy-msgid, sy-msgty, sy-msgv1, sy-msgv2, sy-msgv3, sy-msgv4`?

Comment: If you do not have a possibility to debug it to see what is in those fields then let it dump at this point (I assume you have a possiblity to adjust the coding there). The values in those fields will be then visible in the short dump description in `ST22`. `sy-subrc = 3` is not sufficient to tell what really happens there.

Comment: It seems some other statement producing the `3` sy-subrc, try to add [message clause](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapopen_dataset_error_handling.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@) to OPEN DATASET statement to produce more feedback

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have information that subrc is 3, it is 8 because of the line after OPEN DATASET (if sy-subrc EQ 0 proceed.)

The problem is that I don't have dump analysis since the program after this error proceeds with other lines which are used for writing on the screen. So the job gets finished successfully but the data is not written in the file.

Comment: @Sandra Rossi 

The problem is as i said, i cannot change the code, the job gets finished so there is no dump or error analysis, i just need to provide info why sometimes there is Error opening file error and sometimes it works. I am guessing that there is a problem with big amount of data because for smaller date intervals program works. 

Here are the screenshots of code and error.

https://ibb.co/mNnTTVg
https://ibb.co/9pLMH70
https://ibb.co/8MnqmCG

Comment: @Suncatcher can you please check the comment above with the screenshot, i couldn't tag more than one person.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jagger 
can you please check the comment above, with the screenshot, I couldn't tag more than one person.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible that when you run it for a big data volume, the file name (or folders) contains blanks or special characters? Or is that possible that your ABAP system has several application servers, and for one of them the folder does not exist? (SM51 to see the list of application servers)

Comment: Can it be that you just out of space on application server? Try to check [via ST06](https://i.imgur.com/eRTWaVs.png)

Comment: @SandraRossi the file name should be fine because it works in other cases. (there is a line in the code which is concatenating user name and date + some other things) so the path and file name is always right. 

I also checked the SM51, there are 2 SAP servers but i cannot find how to open second one in the al11 to check if the folder exists, it is by default opening the first one. But again, i think that that might not be the problem because user is defining path+folder+file name, and as i said, it works for smaller intervals (less data)

Comment: @Suncatcher i checked the space, there is 14 GB of free space on the server.

Comment: In SM51, double click the second application server, that will open a new user session connected to that server and run your program in dialog mode with the small data set, so that to make sure SAP can write to the folder in that server too (both servers usually define each a soft link to a shared folder). Note that you can also see in which application server a job has been executed, by displaying its details (transaction code SM37).

Comment: @SandraRossi the situation is like this :
1. When I enter the SM51, I see two servers, but clicking on them is not opening a new session, it is just opening process overview screen. I cannot find a way to see the folders in server#2.

2. What i found interesting, that on the background job list, if there are 3 jobs for that user, two of them have failed and the target server was the 2nd one,but there is one job which succeded in opening the file, his target system is system #1, but the difference is that that job had duration of ~1 hour and not 10 hours like two others.

Comment: Okay, so that seems to be the problem. Talk to your administrator to explain the problem, he should understand and correct that. Note: in SM51, double clicking the other server opens the overview screen in a new user session started in that server. Enter /NSE38 in the command field to start the program in dialog and that will run in that server. You can see to which server your current screen is assigned, by clicking a little button at the very bottom right of the screen. Let me prepare the answer.

Comment: Try to inject check for `sy-sysid` var in your program and check its value on successful and unsuccessful case. But it is very unlikely that the cause is in application server

Comment: @SandraRossi thank you very much, as soon as I test your solution, I will report you what happened.

Comment: @SandraRossi I checked your proposal, the jobs which were finished correctly were pointing to one server, and jobs which were finished incorrectly were pointing to another server in which I don't have the authorization to open that folder in al11.

I told my consultant to check with the client basis team about giving authorizations for that folder so i am waiting for respond from them.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: this answer assumes that the original direction ("because of data volume") was based on a misinterpretation of what happened, because of a simple coincidence. It often happens, but I may be wrong of course. This assumption is based on the latest OP comment: *"What i found interesting, that on the background job list, if there are 3 jobs for that user, two of them have failed and the target server was the 2nd one,but there is one job which succeeded in opening the file, his target system is system #1, but the difference is that that job had duration of ~1 hour and not 10 hours like two others."*)

When you run a background job and there's an error opening a file from time to time, it may be due to the fact that you have an ABAP system with several application servers, and that one of them (at least) is not configured correctly to map a given folder to a "network" folder shared by all other application servers.

To make sure, you can see in which application server the failed job has been executed, by displaying its details (transaction code SM37). Then run the program twice, once in the application server where a job failed, once in the application server where a job succeeded, with the same input parameters.

It should succeed and fail accordingly.

To run a program in a given application server, there are two solutions:

- Either start a job by indicating the desired target application server
- Or switch your SAP GUI user session to the application server you want:

  - Use SM51 to display the list of all application servers
  - double click the concerned server
  - that opens the overview screen in a new user session started in that server
  - Enter /NSE38 in the command field and start the program in dialog (it will run in that server).

Now that it's almost certain this is the cause, **you should ask the administrator** to correct the issue, that in the given application server, he should add a "mapping" from the file folder to the shared folder (do the same as he did in other application servers).

Comment: It is very peculiar that program fails only on big amounts of data. Is messaging server redirects process with big amounts of data only to concrete server? Unlikely

Comment: @suncatcher Or it's simply a human misinterpretation of what happened. It often happens. It's my guess based on latest OP comments.